# flutter_test framework TypeMatcher is Depreciated

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

When using VSCode it warns me that the `TypeMatcher<T>` is depreciated.

[image: IDE Warning]

From the relevant [Dart API docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-matcher_matcher/TypeMatcher-class.html) . . .

```dart
TypeMatcher([@Deprecated('Provide a type argument to TypeMatcher and omit the name. ' 'This argument will be removed in the next release.') String name])
```

**What should I be using instead of `TypeMatcher<T>`?**

output of `Flutter --version`

```sh
  Flutter 1.21.0-9.2.pre • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
  Framework • revision 81a45ec2e5 (3 weeks ago) • 2020-08-27 14:14:33 -0700
  Engine • revision 20a9531835
  Tools • Dart 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-7.3.beta)
```

Answer (score 2):

While reading through the [docs for the matcher library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-matcher_matcher/package-matcher_matcher-library.html) I noticed

> isInstanceOf DEPRECATED Use isA instead. [...]

Checking the [docs for flutter_test](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/flutter_test-library.html) again I found that the same method exists there as well.

**Short Answer**

Old way

```dart
expect(someObject, TypeMathcher<T>);
```

New way

```dart
expect(someObject, isA<T>);
```